# The certificate has an invalid issuer : keychain

Tags: certificate, keychain

found weired issue in keychain. I have number of certificates in keychain. they are works before a day. but now there is a text "the certificate has an invalid issuer" in red color.

doesen't know what to do[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-> Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and double-click to install to Keychain.

-> Select "View" -> "Show Expired Certificates" in Keychain app.

-> Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab in Keychain app.

Now, all certificates are valid

Comment: I had to do this again today even though I had already downloaded and installed the new intermediate cert.  I downloaded and installed the AppleWWDRCA.cer a 2nd time, removed the previous one a 2nd time and it started working again.  Such is the life of Apple Developers.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue you have to follow below steps:

1)   Open Keychain Access 
 2)   Go to View -> Show Expired Certificates
  [image]
 3)   Go to System in Keychain 
[image]
 4)   Here you find that"Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority" is mark as expired. So delete it. 
 5)   Download new [Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) from here.
 6)   Install it by double click on it.

Its done!!!

Comment: Don't forget to check the System keychain for the same expired certificate. I found a duplicate there.